# MySQL: join grouped data to table - only first row joined

Tags: mysql, join, group-by

I have problem joining tables with following content:

Table `RingOrderItem`:

```
+----+-------------+--------+
| ID | ID_RingType | Amount |
+----+-------------+--------+
|  1 | A           |    100 |
|  2 | B           |     50 |
|  3 | A           |    500 |
|  4 | C           |    100 |
+----+-------------+--------+
```

Grouped table `Rings` - result of `SELECT min(Rings.Number) AS Number, ID_RingType FROM Rings GROUP BY ID_RingType` statement:

```
+--------+-------------+
| Number | ID_RingType |
+--------+-------------+
|      1 | A           |
|      1 | B           |
+--------+-------------+
```

I want to retrieve all records from `RingOrderItem` and join number from grouped table `Rings` to them, for which I used this query:

```
SELECT
    roi.ID,
    roi.ID_RingOrder,
    roi.ID_RingType,
    roi.Amount,
    min(r.Number) AS `FromValue`,
    min(r.Number) + roi.Amount - 1 AS `ToValue`
FROM
    RingOrderItem AS roi
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT min(Rings.Number) AS Number, ID_RingType FROM Rings 
        GROUP BY ID_RingType) 
    AS r ON r.ID_RingType = roi.ID_RingType;
```

For some reason, I get only the first row from `RingOrderItem` table:

```
+----+--------------+-------------+--------+-----------+---------+
| ID | ID_RingOrder | ID_RingType | Amount | FromValue | ToValue |
+----+--------------+-------------+--------+-----------+---------+
|  1 |            1 | A           |    100 |         1 |     100 |
+----+--------------+-------------+--------+-----------+---------+
```

I want all rows, and if the data can not be joined (value `C` in `ID_RingType`), than return simply `NULL`.

Thanks,
Zbynek

Comment: Probably because of this bit: Number) AS `FromValue`,
    min(r.Number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need the two min() functions on the main query since you are already getting the min values in the sub query.

Also, it's not really a good idea to do math to a column that might be `NULL`

Try this:

```
SELECT
    roi.ID,
    roi.ID_RingOrder,
    roi.ID_RingType,
    roi.Amount,
    r.Number AS FromValue,
    COALESCE(r.Number, 0) + roi.Amount - 1 AS ToValue
FROM
    RingOrderItem AS roi
LEFT JOIN
    (
        SELECT 
            MIN(Rings.Number) AS Number, 
            ID_RingType 
        FROM 
            Rings 
        GROUP BY 
            ID_RingType
    ) AS r ON roi.ID_RingType = r.ID_RingType;
```

Also, switch your left join ON clause to have the first table listed first.